# Buttons not working in a very simple tkinter app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to generalize the creation of tabs and buttons in a `ttk.Notebook`. Here's what I have so far:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Frame
from tkinter import Button, Tk

f1 = lambda: print("f1")
f2 = lambda: print("f2")
f3 = lambda: print("f3")
f4 = lambda: print("f4")
f5 = lambda: print("f5")
f6 = lambda: print("f6")
f7 = lambda: print("f7")

frames = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
labels = [('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), ('f4', 'f5'), ('f6', 'f7')]
commands = [(f1, f2, f3), (f4, f5), (f6, f7)]

tk = Tk()
notebook = Notebook(tk)

for i, f in enumerate(frames):
  frame = Frame(notebook)
  notebook.add(frame, text=f)
  for j, label in labels[i]:
    button = Button(frame, text=label, command=commands[i])
    button.pack()
notebook.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, when I click on the generated buttons, none of them respond as expected, namely by printing out to the terminal.

Why is my minimal tkinter app not working as expected?

Comment: Did you try to print out `commands[i]`? It is not what you expect.  *Print out some debug messages is a simple way to find out what the issue is*.

Comment: You're right. My code was a mess, I'll post the corrected one in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had several problems with the above script. Here's one that works:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Frame
from tkinter import Button, Tk
import pdb

f1 = lambda: print("f1")
f2 = lambda: print("f2")
f3 = lambda: print("f3")
f4 = lambda: print("f4")
f5 = lambda: print("f5")
f6 = lambda: print("f6")
f7 = lambda: print("f7")

frames = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
labels = [('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), ('f4', 'f5'), ('f6', 'f7')]
commands = [(f1, f2, f3), (f4, f5), (f6, f7)]

tk = Tk()
notebook = Notebook(tk)

for i, f in enumerate(frames):
  frame = Frame(notebook)
  notebook.add(frame, text=f)
  for j, label in enumerate(labels[i]):
    button = Button(frame, text=label, command=commands[i][j])
    button.pack()
notebook.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```